# Будет ли работать Python программа на ПК на котором питон не скачан?

Tags: python, exe

Написал небольшую игру на питоне. Хочу скинуть другу. Будет ли она у него работать если я сделаю из пайтон файла exe файл, но при условий что питон у него на пк не скачан?

Comment: Не так просто в ехе перевести, но если получится, то будет работать

Comment: Вообще если писал с pygame там вроде есть компилятор который собираем весь билд

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Будет. Чтобы собрать exe используй [pyinstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/)
Если у тебя несколько файлов, то вместо
`pyinstaller твой_скрипт.py` используй `pyinstaller --onefile твой_скрипт.py`

---

Чтобы команда выполнилась нужно находится в той же папке, что и твой скрипт.
Перейти в папку со скриптом можно командой `cd /path/to` или, если ты на Windows, `cd C:\path\to` (cd - change directory)

---

`pyinstaller` автоматически соберет все зависимости. Также, если есть желание, можешь поставить ico иконку на свою игру. О том, как это сделать можешь почитать [здесь](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) либо просто загуглить